# Order by inside loop PDO

Tags: php, pdo, php-7.1

```
TOP 3 Players:
```

```
<?php 

$xxx=$ConnectingDB->query("SELECT DISTINCT(who) FROM autoquiz_logs LIMIT 3 ");
while ($xoxo = $xxx->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))   {

    $xxxo=$ConnectingDB->query("SELECT * FROM autoquiz_logs where who ='".$xoxo['who']."'")->rowCount();

    echo ''.getnick($xoxo['who']).': '.$xxxo.' ';
}
?>
```

but my results are:

Player1: 21

Player2: 18

Player3: 61

how do i sort? from highest score to lowest?

Comment: I don't see how the code above could produce an output like `Player1: 21` - `$xxxo` should be an array, and therefore echoing it like that should produce a warning, not a number. Did you over-simplify your example?

Comment: I can't check it out there because a) it requires a login, and b) it doesn't allow me to debug your code anyway. What kind of object is `$ConnectingDB`? Is that the PDO object, or your own custom class?

Comment: yes, the PDO object.

Comment: Sorry but then it's impossible for the code to do what you say. If `$ConnectingDB` is a PDO connection object, then the ->query() method would return a PDOStatement object into $xxxo.  If you try to echo that, you'd get an error like `bject of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string`. if you echo'd `$xxxo->rowCount()` though, you'd get a count of the number of rows.

Comment: Anyway, you can solve your requirement with a single query (instead of two), by using GROUP BY and COUNT